# NodeJS. When creating a file using FS, the error Type Error

Tags: node.js, filesystems

**I tried JSON.stringify, .toString, not work.**

Here is the code:

```
const astCode = (await fs.readFile(filename)).toString();
    const ast = JSON.parse(astCode);
    const jsCode = generate(ast);
    var jsFilename = makename(5);
    var jsFileNameEm = `${jsFilename}.js`;
    await fs.writeFile(jsFileNameEm, JSON.stringify(jsCode, null, 2), { encoding: "utf-8" });
    console.log(`Wrote ${jsFileNameEm}.`);
```

On startup, it throws an error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
> at writeFileSync (node:fs:2211:5)
> at main (sketch/src/parser/generator.js:28:11).

I am using readFileSync and writeFileSync from FS

Comment: Seems like `jsCode === undefined` and thus also `JSON.stringify(jsCode) === undefined `

Comment: no, you say like everyone else, there is information there, there is no undefined.

Comment: The error clearly says otherwise...

Comment: Believe me, you are wrong, I parse and generate everything from a file, there is a json.

Comment: As I don't know what the content of the file you are reading is, nor what `generate()` does,  I can only believe what's written in the error message you cited. And it clearly says you are passing `undefined` as second parameter ...

Comment: Furthermore you (and the error message) are talking about `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync`, yet in the code shown you are using the FS promise API. Are you sure you are looking at the right place in the code?

Comment: I'm saying that I'm parsing data in the form of AST from a json file, and I tried to read and create files in different ways, I deleted fs promise imports, and imported readFileSync and writeFileSync, did not help. So what is passed in the second argument is not equal to undefined.

Comment: It's not about imports, and not about the – data !== undefined!!!.

Comment: I can only repeat myself. What you pass as second argument (ie the result of `JSON.stringify(jsCode, null, 2)`) to `fs.writeFileSync` is -- according to the error message -- `undefined` And the only possiblity that `JSON.stringify` returns `undefined` is, when its first argument is `undefined`. Set a breakpoint in your code and check the value of `jsCode` before you try to write it to a file. Assign the result of `JSON.stringify(jsCode, null, 2)` to a variable and check its value ... Add a condition `if (jsCode !== undefined)` before you write to file ...

Comment: and what should I do when the value undefined?

Comment: you somehow explained everything on the knee that nothing is clear. Data second, not equal to undefined. Let me give you access to the repository, will you download and see?

Comment: https://github.com/spelsinx/sketch – src/parser/testsparse.js (generator ast.json, after which comes the generation part in generator.js generates javascript code and writes it to a file with a random name.

Comment: Your repository doesn't have a `package.json` thus I cannot install dependencies and thus I cannot run any tests. And which command should I run to do any tests? But honestly, I don't really want to debug your code. The error is clear: You are passing undefined data to `writeFile`. To find out, why your data is undfined is up to yourself (or make this question so self contained, that there is no need to clone any external repositories ...)

Comment: you need to download nearley (compiler nearleyc), and moo. And how to make a question anonymous, please help

Comment: can you post few lines of the variable jsCode please ?

Comment: having a look into the file that is referenced in the error message (ie `src/src/parser/generator.js`)  and the `generate()` function there, I can see, that this function returns a value IF AND ONLY IF `node.operation === 'assign'`. In all other cases it returns `undefined`. I don't know the contents of the file you are reading, but are you sure, this condition holds? Looking at the file `9kME3.ast.json` which is mentioned in the comments, it's pretty obvious, that that condition CAN'T hold, because that file contains an array, and you are passing the whole array into `generate(ast)`  ...

Comment: @RamiDridi I uploaded the above code to github, you can see it in the file src/parser/generator.js

Comment: BTW `await readFileSync()` doesn't make any sense in a `async` environment. In fact it's really bad, because it blocks the whole process. Use `readFile/writeFile` from `node:fs/promises` instead

Comment: @derpirscher i.e. should I handle all cases?

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: You should pass the correct object to that function. Ie either only pass single nodes to `generate` or make `generate` capable of handling arrays ...

Comment: ok, I'll try to improve the generator function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248857/discussion-between-tim-and-derpirscher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the code in git it had this :

```
     if (node.operation === "assign") {
    const varName = node.identifier.value;
    const value = node["value"].value; // SUCCESS 7:11 19 SEPTEMBER.
    return `let ${varName} = ${value};`;
       //return [`let ${varName} = ${value};`, `console.log(${varName})`];
      //return [(`let h = 0;`), (`let s = 2`)]
       }
```

while it should be this :

```
     if (node[0].operation === "assign") {
    const varName = node[0].identifier.value;
    const value = node[0].value.value // SUCCESS 7:11 19 SEPTEMBER.
    return `let ${varName} = ${value};`;
    //return [`let ${varName} = ${value};`, `console.log(${varName})`];
   //return [(`let h = 0;`), (`let s = 2`)]
   }
```

because most of the files seemed to contain a list of objects, and you were accessing object keys instead of array indexes first.

PS : this

```
node generator.js ./ast/9kME3.ast.json
```

worked and returned this:

```
Wrote kAEie.js.
```

inside that file :

```
let s = 3 + 3;
```

Comment: What if the array index is not 0?

Comment: Could you help with this as well? "    const astCode = (await fs.readFileSync(filename)).toString();
    const ast = JSON.parse(astCode);
    const jsCode = generate(ast);
    var jsFilename = makename(5);
    var jsFileNameEm = `${jsFilename}.js`;
    await fs.writeFileSync(jsFileNameEm, jsCode);
    console.log(`Wrote ${jsFileNameEm}.`);" returns "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined"

Comment: I didn't go through all the files, but you have to check data structure before condition, if it's an array, you'll have to loop through it specially if it has more than 1 element

Comment: I don't quite understand, but thanks